# Is my TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10 using the 64-bit binaries?

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I downloaded the 64-bit binaries for TeX Live 2021 on Windows 10 from https://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64/. I have the sub-directories S:\tex\bin\win32 and S:\tex\bin\win64. When running `tlmgr conf`, I get:

> PATH:
> S:\tex\tlpkg\tlperl\bin;S:\tex\bin\win32;...;S:\tex\bin\win64;S:\tex\bin\win32;S:\Programs\gs\bin;S:\tex\tlpkg\tlgs\bin;S:\Programs\gs\gsview;S:\Programs\gs\pstoedit;S:\Programs\gnuplot\bin;S:\Programs\Perl\c\bin;S:\Programs\Perl\perl\site\bin;S:\Programs\Perl\perl\bin;S:\Programs\Ruby\bin;S:\Programs\Ruby\Ruby\bin;S:\Programs\Python;S:\Programs\Python\Scripts;S:\Programs\Python\Launcher;S:\Programs\msys\usr\bin;S:\Programs\msys\usr\lib;S:\Programs\msys\mingw64\bin;S:\Programs\msys\mingw64\sbin;S:\Programs\msys\mingw64\lib;S:\Programs\CMake\bin;S:\Programs\Git\cmd;...
>
> dvipdfmx:  S:/tex/bin/win32/dvipdfmx.EXE
> dvips:     S:/tex/bin/win32/dvips.EXE
> fmtutil:   S:/tex/bin/win32/fmtutil.EXE
> kpsewhich: S:/tex/bin/win32/kpsewhich.EXE
> luatex:    S:/tex/bin/win32/luatex.EXE
> mktexpk:   S:/tex/bin/win32/mktexpk.EXE
> pdftex:    S:/tex/bin/win32/pdftex.EXE
> tex:       S:/tex/bin/win32/tex.EXE
> tlmgr:     S:/tex/bin/win32/tlmgr.BAT
> updmap:    S:/tex/bin/win32/updmap.EXE
> xetex:     S:/tex/bin/win32/xetex.EXE

This tells me that TeX Live is not invoking the 64-bit binaries. This is possibly caused by the first instance of `S:\tex\bin\win32`. PATH later shows `S:\tex\bin\win64;S:\tex\bin\win32`, which is what I have under System Environment Variables in Windows---`S:\tex\bin\win64` followed by `S:\tex\bin\win32` as requested in https:///mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64/00README.TLW64. It is then apparent that the first two entries `S:\tex\tlpkg\tlperl\bin;S:\tex\bin\win32` in the PATH shown above are introduced by the TeX Live installation routines and could be defined in some configuration file somewhere in my `S:\tex`. Is my install proper per the above? Should the first instance of `S:\tex\bin\win32` be there in the PATH above? How can one know if TeX Live is invoking the 64-bit binaries or the 32-bit binaries?

Comment: [Akira Kakuto](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/72084/akira-kakuto) might have an insight as he seems to have put together the [TeX Live 64-bit package](https://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/w32tex/TLW64/).

Comment: if you want to use the 64bit binaries you have to ensure that the win64 path is before the win32 path (but both must be there). If needed adapt the path settings in windows.

Comment: Yes, I do have that as I stated in my posting. But I needed to do further work as I explained in the comment to Siep's answer. Anyway, the [batchfile](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/tl64.bat) does a comprehensive job and should be used for a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tlmgr only manages the 32-bit part of the installation.

The TL command-line shortcut which gets created on installation of TL puts the 32-bit binaries at the front. You  need to create an second command-line shortcut with the 64-bit binaries at the front, followed by the 32-bit binaries. [The TL Windows page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html) contains a link to a [batchfile](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/tl64.bat) which automates the download, installation and management of the 64-bit binaries and also creates such a shortcut. If you go this way, you should also look at the [README](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/tl64.README).

Comment: Apologies for not reading enough. That does it. For the benefit of others---Based on Siep's explanation, one could copy the batch file tl-cmd.bat in tlroot/tlpkg/installer, rename the copy (say with x64), open it in a text editor, change win32 to win64, save, and close. To ensure that the path is handled properly (%tlroot%\bin\win64;%tlroot%\bin\win32;%%path%%), one should use the [batchfile](http://www.tug.org/texlive/files/tl64.bat) @Siep pointed to. It does a comprehensive job.